# Conflicting version numbers

Tags: cumulative-update

I'm getting two conflicting version number reports from one of our Sharepoint 2007 sites.

The Site Settings page shows 12.0.0.6557 (April CU) - which is what I expected to see.
However, the HTTP Response Header shows 12.0.0.**6421** (SP2).

I installed the CU myself.

Does anyone here know why this might be so?

Versioning problems tend to have consequences, so I'd like to find and fix this one as soon as I can.

Thanks in advance
Josh

Comment: Are you using WSS or MOSS? If MOSS: Make sure you have installed the WSS *and* MOSS updates to aviod problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTTP Header may not be the right indication of actual version of SharePoint. If CU was successfully applied and central Admin Reflects that, you should be fine. It appears that Http Header reflects only original versions and major upgrades like Service Packs. Check out this as well: http://blog.sharepointsite.co.uk/2011/02/what-version-of-sharepoint-do-i-have_05.html

Comment: Thanks, Ashish. What prompted me to post this question in the first place was that we've got one server whose HTTP header does show the "current" version number (12.0.0.6557). That might possibly be because it's a 64-bit server, whereas the 32-bit server shows what you describe.

Comment: Guess what? It's in a place so obvious I never thought to look for it there.

IIS Manager has a section titled HTTP Response Headers. By gum, one of those headers is MicrosoftSharepointTeamServices, and you set its value MANUALLY.

Comment: Thanks for letting everyone know. You can keep both version in sync manually.